# Deploy QuickAction using a Flow: impossible?

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, deployment, quickaction, sfdx-error

I have an error while deploying a simple QuickAction using a Flow Definition (generated from a force:source:pull)

The flow definition is in the same package so available, but i have an error telling **missing required field [Component]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuickAction xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flowDefinition>MyFlowDefinition</flowDefinition>
    <label>MyFlow</label>
    <optionsCreateFeedItem>false</optionsCreateFeedItem>
    <type>Flow</type>
</QuickAction>
```

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickaction.htm), use of type Flow is in beta since 2019... do anyone know a workaround to deploy such items ?

[image]

Comment: why are you using `FlowDefinition`? That applies only to V43 and earlier. One should only need `Flow` now

Comment: The metadata is retrieved from a scratch org on api version 50 or 51 (Flo & quick action has been configured by a consultant) , so I think Flow is used, but flowDefinition is the name of the metadata attribute on QuickAction

Comment: I checked my org and assuming `MyFlowDefinition` is the API name of the `Flow`, not the `FlowDefinition` in your package; then what you have should work; `Flow` and `FlowDefinition` are different Metadata objecttypes

Comment: I agree it should... but it does not, it requests for a [Component] item, it seems that type:Flow is not well managed ... :/

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue today and managed to resolve it by checking that both Flow and FlowDefinition files are deployed using correct filenames and label to the org. If the QuickAction is referencing a flow that does not exists you seem to get the `missing required field [Component]` error, which easily leads you to believe that you are missing something from your XML definition, but actually it is just not able to locate the referenced flow in the org.

Given your XML, you should have `flows/MyFlowDefinition.flow-meta.xml` (containing label "MyFlowDefinition") and `flowDefinitions/MyFlowDefinition.flowDefinition-meta.xml` definitions to be able to deploy the referencing QuickAction.